# How to unnest data and obtain the first element from an array in SparkR?

Tags: r, apache-spark, data-science, sparkr

I am new to SparkR and trying first steps of data preparation.The dataset is something of this kind. I was trying to subset and select significant columns. My question is how can I select a column from an array element. I was trying something like this, which allowed me to select columns by un-nesting data but couldn't unnest and flatten the array to get it's first element. Helpful [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVSFc.png)

```
select.col <- SparkR::select(data,c("parsed.nid","parsed.status","parsed.sections.element[0].name"))
```

Comment: What does the original structure of the dataset look like? Can you post the output of a `printSchema` in your post as well?

Comment: I have already added it in the post.Please refer to the link provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I myself found a way to resolve this issue.This can be done in two simple steps :-

1. First we need to use explode() in SparkR, to get all the contents in
   the list from that column.
2. Next, we need to use windowPartitionBy() in SparkR to create a
   partitions and then we can get anything we want based on our
   requirements like row_number(),dense_rank(),rank() etc. Like here we want the first element of the list, so I have used row_number function.

Snippet :

```
    data.select <- SparkR::select(data,c("parsed.nid","parsed.status","parsed.sections"))
    names(data.select) <- c("nid","status","sections")
    categories <- SparkR::select(data.select,data.select$nid,data.select$status,explode(data.select$sections))
    ws <- SparkR::orderBy(SparkR::windowPartitionBy("nid","status","sections"),"nid")
    data.final <- SparkR::mutate(categories,row_num = over(row_number(), ws))
    ##If we want to get the first element of the array.
    data.final <- data.final[data.final$row_num==1,]
```

Please add your suggestions as well.